# AWS unreachable after creating AMIs reachable again

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

So one of our AWS instances (running ubuntu 18.04) was unreachable, I wanted to restart it but just in case first create a AMI (image) so booting up a new one would be fast and easy..

But while AWS was pending the creation of the AMI, the instance became reachable again..

I have no idea if creating the image solved it (it was down for 10 hours) and if it did so, how that worked. Does AWS silently reboots the instance when creating an image?

Does any one know more about this?

Comment: Creating an AMI doesn't affect anything about the instance. Unfortunately you haven't given us enough information to help you. What made it become unreachable? Did you change something? Did it update? Can you roll back to a snapshot? Does it have critical data? In that case you can mount the disk to a working instance and copy the data off to a new instance.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your response, We haven't changed anything and I don't think AWS automatically updates anything? Currently the instance is up and running again but I am not sure how it got unreachable or how it was solved again. The instance was stable for multiple weeks.. I am trying to figure out how it became "unstable" or actually how it became unreachable. (no clue where to start)

Comment: AWS doesn't update anything unless you tell it to, however Ubuntu may run automatic updates at the OS level. When it's unavailable you need to do some diagnostics - what services are up and down (http / ssh / ping), if you can ssh in what does top say, etc. If it keeps doing it you might be best off building a new instance and migrating your data over.

Comment: @Tim The problem was that ssh and http were down, and it was in the night so we didn't had the chance to check ping. Is there a way I could check it afterwards? syslog for example? (if so, where should I look for?)

Comment: @goosmaster how did you create the AMI? Console, cli, SDK, ...?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot via the web interface (console.aws.amazon.com)

Comment: @goosmaster did you check the "No reboot" box when creating the AMI?  It isn't checked by default.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No I did not do that, thanks Now that mystery is solved, but sadly I have no idea how it became unreachable, either way thank you for your answer!